# Dependency to __libm_sse2_sincos_ in release

Tags: math, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, linker

I am compiling a static library with msvc 2017 that has a dependency to `math.h`.

On debug mode, I am able to use this library to build an executable. On release mode, a dependency to `__libm_sse2_sincos_` appears on a function that uses consecutively `cos` and `sin`.

Here's the function

```
Complex<double> polar(const double magnitude, const double radian) {
    const double re = magnitude * cos(radian);
    const double im = magnitude * sin(radian);
    return Complex<double>(re, im);
}
```

The code is compiled with `/arch:AVX2`, `/fp:fast` and `/MT`.

Where does this symbol comes from? From a quick Google search, it appears to be somehow related to Intel, but I don't have the Intel compiler or anything related installed on my machine.

Is there a way to track where does this symbol comes from? Or a way to avoid a dependency to it?

Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. works *OK* with *VStudio Community 2017* (*v15.9.15*). I had to simplify the code a bit as compiler didn't know about *Complex*. Are you using some 3rd-party *lib*s? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: __libm_sse2_sincos:it as computation of sine and cosine of the same number.I suggest you could refer to the [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/295531). Please provide us more details to to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @CristiFati I was able to reproduce the call to `_libm_sse2_sincos` https://godbolt.org/z/Yqbe1P But as I said, it happened when I link with a static library using this code, I dont think im able to reproduce online.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol `__libm_sse2_sincos_` comes from MSVC CRT. Your code computes `sin` and `cos` of the same value, so the compiler optimizes the two calls into one (`sincos`), SSE2 version. After you link with the CRT, due to `/MT`, all CRT functions, including that one, will be embedded in your executable.

If you called `sin` and `cos` with different arguments, you'd get two separate calls `___libm_sse2_sin` and `___libm_sse2_cos` ([link to godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/anbsMq)).

If there's a problem linking with the function, then it could be that the release project setup is corrupted.

Note: functions beginning with `__` are reserved for implementation and don't have to be documented. Also, MSVC CRT is not open source (part of it is, but not the math part).